# How to run href # by means of javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know how I can direct a href = "#url" from the same page by means of javascript, without having to click url.

For example I have this code:

```
<p id = "#url" place where address>  <p>;

<a href="#url"> url <a>
```

How to execute the #url click on the same page using javascript.

Comment: `window.location.hash = 'url';`

Comment: That's what I meant thanks is just what I was looking for